# numpy.sum behaves differently on numpy.array vs pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

In short, `numpy.sum(a, axis=None)` sums all cells of an array, but sums over rows of a data frame. I thought that `pandas.DataFrame` is built on top of `numpy.array`, and should not have this different behavior? What's the under-the-hood conversion?

```
a1 = numpy.random.random((3,2))
a2 = pandas.DataFrame(a1)
numpy.sum(a1) # Sums all cells
numpy.sum(a2) # Sums over rows
```

Comment: Odd, it looks like the `axis=None` is being overridden and set to `axis=0` when it goes through the df

Comment: OK, I've tracked this down on line 3980: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py because `axis=None` it's being assigned to `self._stat_axis_number` which is `0`, hence the difference in behaviour

Comment: Why not use `numpy.sum(a2.values)`?

Comment: Starting with pandas 2.0, pandas also does all cells. "For DataFrames, specifying axis=None will apply the aggregation across both axes." https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the following is a dump of my pdb debugging session which shows how this ends up in pandas land:

```
In [*]:

a1 = np.random.random((3,2))
import pdb
a2 = pd.DataFrame(a1)
print(np.sum(a1)) # Sums all cells
pdb.set_trace()
np.sum(a2) # Sums over rows
3.02993889742
--Return--
> <ipython-input-50-92405dd4ed52>(5)<module>()->None
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) b 6
Breakpoint 2 at <ipython-input-50-92405dd4ed52>:6
(Pdb) c
> <ipython-input-50-92405dd4ed52>(6)<module>()->None
-> np.sum(a2) # Sums over rows
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py(1623)sum()
-> def sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
(Pdb) print(axis)
None
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py(1700)sum()
-> if isinstance(a, _gentype):
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py(1706)sum()
-> elif type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
(Pdb) sssssss
*** NameError: name 'sssssss' is not defined
(Pdb) ss
*** NameError: name 'ss' is not defined
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py(1707)sum()
-> try:
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py(1708)sum()
-> sum = a.sum
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py(1713)sum()
-> return sum(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out)
(Pdb) print(axis)
None
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py(3973)stat_func()
-> @Substitution(outname=name, desc=desc)
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py(3977)stat_func()
-> if skipna is None:
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py(3978)stat_func()
-> skipna = True
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py(3979)stat_func()
-> if axis is None:
(Pdb) s
> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.2.4\python-3.4.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py(3980)stat_func()
-> axis = self._stat_axis_number
(Pdb) print(self._stat_axis_number)
0
(Pdb)
```

So basically once it ends up in pandas land there are some integrity checks, one of which is that if `axis is None` then it's assigned the value from `self._stat_axis_number` which is `0`, hence the difference in behaviour. I'm not a pandas dev so they may shed more light on this but this explains the difference in output

In order to achieve the same output you have to call `sum` twice:

```
In [6]:

a2.sum(axis=0).sum()
Out[6]:
3.9180334059883006
```

Or

```
In [7]:

np.sum(np.sum(a2))
Out[7]:
3.9180334059883006
```

Comment: Thanks for the tracing the source! What should be my mental model about `pandas.DataFrame`? Hitherto I've thought about it as `numpy.array`, but given this, it's not always appropriate.

Comment: You should think of it as built using numpy arrays in my opinion, also don't expect all numpy functions to behave the same, there will always be corner cases like this