# Summing resampled data in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to relearn python and use it to help filter and organize data. I am brand new to pandas and have run into the following issue.  I have a sensor that measures falling objects diameters, and velocities. This data is saved to a csv file with the following format:

```
Date,Time,Diameter,Velocity,BaseV

21-Sep-2013,13:51:04,0.422705,0.850142,4.880371
21-Sep-2013,14:01:37,0.505481,1.499196,4.877930
21-Sep-2013,14:18:50,0.391306,1.795166,4.880371
21-Sep-2013,14:18:50,0.407307,1.149977,4.880371
21-Sep-2013,14:18:50,0.399387,2.098552,4.880371
```

Where date and time are when the object fell, diameter and velocity are just that, and baseVoltage it a value we use for calibration.
The instrument measures at the sub-second level, and I am using pandas to resample the data into 5 minute intervals, instead of messing around with modulo division for time values. After going through the panda’s cookbook, I have come up the following code:

```
# Python script to open eachDrop.dat and read values into pandas.dataframe 
import math as m
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------       
#read csv values into panda data frame
dropData=pd.read_csv('resEachDrop[RD130921.dat].txt',sep=',',header=0,index_col=0,parse_dates=[[0,1]],encoding=None,tupleize_cols=False,           infer_datetime_format=True)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#resample time series to 5min intervals for Count, Mean, Min and Max
#mmmsc/s is group of np functions to apply to dropData diameter column to return aggregated columns 

mmmsc={'Mean':np.mean, 'Max':np.max, 'Min':np.min, 'Sum':np.sum,'Count':'count'}
mmms={'Mean':np.mean, 'Max':np.max, 'Min':np.min, 'Sum':np.sum}
#resample dropData at 5min increment on Diameter column using mhc
newData=dropData.resample('5Min', how={'Diameter':mmmsc,'Velocity':mmms})
print newData
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output to the terminal window looks like this (I have removed some of the lines to save space):

```
Date_Time Diameter  Velocity     BaseV
2013-09-21 13:51:04  0.422705  0.850142  4.880371
2013-09-21 14:01:37  0.505481  1.499196  4.877930
2013-09-21 14:18:50  0.391306  1.795166  4.880371
2013-09-21 14:18:50  0.407307  1.149977  4.880371
...                       ...       ...       ...
2013-09-21 23:59:54  0.470808  0.719216  4.216309
2013-09-21 23:59:54  0.529965  1.748123  4.216309
2013-09-21 23:59:55  0.563966  1.466564  4.213867
2013-09-21 23:59:55  0.563966  1.515517  4.213867

[53740 rows x 3 columns]
                     Diameter                                             
Date_Time  Count       Max          Sum       Min      Mean

2013-09-21 13:50:00         1  0.422705     0.422705  0.422705  0.422705
2013-09-21 13:55:00         0       NaN          NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-09-21 14:00:00         1  0.505481     0.505481  0.505481  0.505481
2013-09-21 14:05:00         0       NaN          NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-09-21 14:10:00         0       NaN          NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-09-21 14:15:00         3  0.407307     1.198000  0.391306  0.399333
...                       ...       ...          ...       ...       ...
2013-09-21 21:30:00      1068  3.614623   594.918064  0.385087  0.557039
2013-09-21 21:35:00       247  4.363684   136.175383  0.384975  0.551317
2013-09-21 21:40:00       176  1.284766    92.519502  0.393808  0.525679 
2013-09-21 21:45:00       147  1.642836    79.037770  0.385874  0.537672
                     Velocity
                          Max          Sum       Min      Mean
Date_Time
2013-09-21 13:50:00  0.850142     0.850142  0.850142  0.850142
2013-09-21 13:55:00       NaN          NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-09-21 14:00:00  1.499196     1.499196  1.499196  1.499196
2013-09-21 14:05:00       NaN          NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-09-21 14:10:00       NaN          NaN       NaN       NaN
2013-09-21 14:15:00  2.098552     5.043695  1.149977  1.681232
...                       ...          ...       ...       ...
2013-09-21 21:30:00  3.040620  1589.967392  0.433960  1.488734
2013-09-21 21:35:00  3.215267   376.540780  0.425394  1.524457
2013-09-21 21:40:00  2.362207   272.548852  0.529707  1.548573
2013-09-21 21:45:00  2.285334   228.478854  0.503430  1.554278
```

When comparing the sum values for diameter, to the sum values calculated by the program that processes the data, I have a tremendous error. After searching the forums I think that this is due to numpy.sum taking the sum across the rows instead of the columns similar to this issue:
[numpy.sum behaves differently on numpy.array vs pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798618/numpy-sum-behaves-differently-on-numpy-array-vs-pandas-dataframe)
.
I have tried to adjust the Sum':np.sum, to use axis=0 similar to the solution in this thread, but I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "dropRead.py", line 12, in <module>
mmmsc={'Mean':np.mean, 'Max':np.max, 'Min':np.min, 'Sum':np.sum(axis=0),
'Count':'count'}
TypeError: sum() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I can do to get the column to sum correctly?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: What does "correct" look like to you? Could you provide an example of the output you are looking for?

Comment: try using `pd.Series.sum` instead of `np.sum` this will sum the columns

Answer (score 0):

My issue was fixed using EdChum's suggestion:

```
pd.Series.sum
```

instead of:

```
np.sum
```